# Find minimum of the $n$ such $x+11y+11z=n$ has $16653$ triples of postive integers solution

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I wish to solve following problem
$$x+11y+11z=n(n\in N^{+})$$ has $16653$ triples $(x,y,z)$ of postive integers.

Find $n_{\min}$

Of course, I can't solve it by Now, so there any solution?

**Problem 2**: let $a_{n}$ be numbers of triples $(x,y,z)$ of postive integers such that
$$x+11y+11z=n$$
Find a closed form for the $a_{n}$?

Comment: 1) What have you tried ? 2) What do you mean by "find closed $a_n$ "?  A closed form for the $a_n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be separated in two operations:

(op. 1) find all $x,k \in \mathbb{N^*}$ such that $x+11k=n \ \ (1) \ $, then

(op. 2) find all $y,z \in \mathbb{N^*}$ such that $y+z=k \ \ (2)$.

Let $m=\lfloor n/11 \rfloor $ (integer part of $n/11$).

For any  $k=2\cdots m$, there are $k-1$ solutions to (2), thus $k-1$ sol. to (1) as well.

As $k$ cannot exceed $m$ (as can be seen from (2)), the total number of solutions in $\mathbb{N^*}$ is:

*** from here, changes have been made  ***

$$\begin{cases}1+2+\cdots+(m-1)=m(m-1)/2 & \text{if n is not a multiple of 11}\\
1+2+\cdots+(m-2)=(m-2)(m-1)/2 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

This separation in two cases, signaled by @geromty (I had not seen it), comes from the fact that if $n$ is a multiple of $11$, one must not give value $0$ to $x$.

Thus:

- either $n$ is not a multiple of $11$ and we solve $m(m-1)/2=16653$, with integer solution $m=183$, then find the smallest $n$ such that $\lfloor n/11 \rfloor =183$, **with $n$ non multiple of $11$**. This value is $n=11 \times 183+1=2014$.
- or we have to solve $(m-2)(m-1)/2=16653$ giving $m=184$ and thus  $n = 11 \times 184 = 2024$, which is higher than $2014$.

So the answer to the problem is $n=2014$.

Comment: Hello,why $\dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}=16653?$ not $\dfrac{m(m-1)}{2}=16653?$$

Comment: you are right, it's a typo. I correct it.

Comment: In fact, I think I have a shift of one unit. I have to correct it.

Comment: Thanks,ButI found have some wrong,because $[n/11]=183$,I think $n=11\times 183+1=2014?$

Comment: No, you have not to add 1.

Comment: why?  the book has only answer $2014$.on the words, if you are true $(n=2013)$?we can determin the equation $x+11y+11z=2013$ has $16653$ solutions?

Comment: I think $n=2014$, because if $n=2013$,then $x+11k=2013$, you mean $k=183$ but $x=0$ not such postive integers

Comment: You are right. I have corrected my text.